# Creation of ID3D12Device10

Tags: directx, directx-12

How does one obtain a `ID3D12Device10` handle from `D3D12CreateDevice()`? For me it fails with the error "No such interface supported". It works fine with `ID3D12Device6`. I'm on Windows 11 21H2 22000.856, and the SDK version is 10.0.22000.0. `QueryInterface()` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for `ID3D12Device10` / `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList7` requires either *Windows 11, Version 22H2* or *Windows 10 Version 1909* or later or *Windows 11* while using the [DirectX Agility SDK](https://aka.ms/directx12agility) version 1.7 which is currently in preview.

On your current system, `ID3D12Device9` / `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList6` is the highest supported by default.

Exactly which features are exposed on your system depends on the video driver, so be sure to use **CheckFeatureSupport**.